# 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /www/cgibin/webadmin.cgi on this server

Tags: linux, apache, http-status-code-403, debian-stretch

I have a apache2 server with linux/debian. Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u1

I have in the same directory an `index.cgi` and `webadmin.cgi`.  The directory is `/var/www/html/renacimientos.be/www/cgibin/`.

`index.cgi` is a little cgi for test. It works.  When I try to run `webadmin.cgi`, it returns an **error 403**.

**/etc/apache2/conf-available/renacimientos-cgi-bin.conf**

```
LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
            Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
            Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
    ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/var/www/html/renacimientos.be/www/cgibin"
            <Directory "/var/www/html/renacimientos.be/www/cgibin">
                    AllowOverride None
                    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
                    Require all granted

                     <Files ~ (\.cgi$)>
                     SetHandler cgi-script
                     Options ExecCGI
                     </Files>
            </Directory>
    </IfDefine>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
ServerName localhost
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

<IfModule alias_module>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/ cgibin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
 AllowOverride None
 Options ExecCGI
 SetHandler cgi-script
 Require all granted
</Directory>

LogLevel warn

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Verify that your file permissions are the same on both files.  Then verify your error_log file to see if Apache reports any error from the execution of the script.  You should put your `LogLevel debug` before you do that test.